# Show drop down item on select first time and hide on select same item second time

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. How to show form_input when selected C and hide when selected A,B,D.
2. When selected C next time then that time also form_input is hide. i.e. suppose first time select C then it will show the form_input but seconf time when selected C then that time it will hide the form_input.

Anyone can tell how to do this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="pm">
  <select name="pay">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
  </select>
</div>

<form class="form_input">
<input type="text" placeholder="write something"/>
</form>

<script>
$('.pm').on('change', "select[name='pay']", function(ev) {
    if($(ev.currentTarget.selectedOptions).text()=== "C"){
        $("#form_input").show();
    }
    else{
    $("#form_input").hide();
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I edit my question **first point** is done. kindly, give the solution for second point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 var firstTime = true;

        $('.pm').on('change', "select[name='pay']", function (ev) {
            if ($(ev.currentTarget.selectedOptions).text() === "C" && firstTime == true) {
                console.clear();
                console.log("C is printed");
                $('#theInput').css("display", "block");
                firstTime = false;
            }
            else {
               // ev.empty();
                $('#theInput').css("display", "none");
            }
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <div class="pm">
        <select name="pay">
            <option>A</option>
            <option>B</option>
            <option>C</option>
            <option>D</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <form class="form_input">
        <input type="text" id="theInput" placeholder="write something" style="display:none;"/>
    </form>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. 1st point is done. kindly, provide some solution for 2nd point.

Comment: When selected C next time then that time also form_input is hide. i.e. suppose first time select C then it will show the form_input but seconf time when selected C then that time it will hide the form_input. @ Daniel Lord

Answer (score 1):

You could use an attribute to know if C option has been shown. Check this snippet.Regards

```js
$('.form_input').hide();
$('.pm').on('change', "select[name='pay']", function(ev) {
    if($(ev.currentTarget.selectedOptions).text()=== "C"){
        console.clear();
        
        
        if ($(this).attr('shown')) {
          $('.form_input').hide();
        } else{
          $('.form_input').show();
         console.log("C is printed");
         $(this).attr('shown', true);
        }
        
    }
    else{
      $('.form_input').hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="pm">
  <select name="pay">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
  </select>
</div>

<form class="form_input">
<input type="text" placeholder="write something"/>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Albesis.. it work but when selected C continuously it will break..
i.e. select C 1st time then again selected C 2nd time when selected rest items.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong selector, use `.` instead of `#` as form has class `form_input` and not id. Anyways you need to track selection for `C`, try this example

```js
$(function() {
  var countOfC = 0;
  $('select[name=pay]').on('change', function() {
    console.log('selected', this.value);
    $('form.form_input').hide();
    if ('C' === this.value) {
      countOfC++;
      if (1 === countOfC) {
        $('form.form_input').show();
      } else {
        console.log('selected before, hence not shown');
      }
    }
  }).trigger('change'); /* page load trigger */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="pm">
  <select name="pay">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
  </select>
</div>

<form class="form_input">
  <input type="text" placeholder="write something" />
</form>
```

Comment: select `c` and select `c` again, won't hide the input

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd have done that.

Bind a click event, so you can see what is being selected everytime whether selected values changes or not. So, you can handle it if user selects `C` and then `C` again

```js
var flag = true;
$('select[name="pay"]').on('click',function(ev){
    if(ev.offsetY < 0){
      if(['A','B','D'].indexOf($("select[name='pay'] :selected").text()) >= 0){
     $('.input').hide();
   }
   if($("select[name='pay'] :selected").text() ==='C' && flag ){
      $('.input').show();
       
      flag = false;
   } else{
   $('.input').hide();
   } 
    }else{
      
    }
});
```

```css
.input{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="pm">
  <select name="pay">
    <option class="options">A</option>
    <option class="options">B</option>
    <option class="options">C</option>
    <option class="options">D</option>
  </select>
</div>

<form class="form_input">
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="write something"/>
</form>
 
</body>
</html>
```